# How to keep the same pediatrician

Tags: united-states, job-change, benefits, insurance

I'm looking at switching jobs and the new provider doesn't have our paediatrician in its network.  My son has had a few health problems and we wouldn't want to change doctors or specialist.  Is it possible to get a separate plan that or paediatrician would take just for our kids?

Is there a different option or am I just stuck?

Comment: Where are you located? Answers to this question will be highly dependent on location. In the US most insurance plans have a process you can go through to be able to continue care with an existing provider. Not sure how successful people are with that. Also, some insurance plans have "out of network" benefits. Does the employer offer a plan that has that?

Comment: I guess since you mentioned medicare you are located in the US. If that's not the case, feel free to tag with a different country. But I think this needs at least a country to answer.

Comment: As a side note to your question, some times the only reason a provider isn't in a given network is because they've never been recruited. You may want to ask your provider if they would consider joining the network used by the new plan.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it possible to get a separate plan that or pediatrician would take
>   just for our kids?

Certainly.

There is nothing that requires you to get your health insurance from your employer. You are always free to purchase insurance on the open market.

That insurance could cover your entire family, or just selected family members.

Comment: With the caveat being that if you don't purchase insurance through your employer, then they won't help cover any of the costs either.

Comment: @DavidK That is typical, but not always the case - I'm aware of some companies that give a health insurance stipend if you choose not to use the company plan.

Comment: It's also important to at least roughly price out the cost of using the same pediatrician as an out-of-network benefit (available in insurance plan documentation), possibilities of referrals from an in-network pediatrician to your current one, and the cost of a different insurance plan. Some plans might give you intermediate options, like an HSA. The pediatrician may also offer attractive prices if you pay for services upfront in full without using insurance.